# Why do elements of my 2-d array repeat itself?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

```
int[] speed = {25, 30, 35, 40, 45};//MPH
double[] deg = {25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};//deg

int rows = speed.length;
int columns = deg.length;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        trajectory[i][j] = ((Math.pow((speed[i] / 2.237), 2) * Math.sin(2 * Math.toRadians(deg[j]))) / gravity);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5d   ", speed[i]);  
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%9.2f", trajectory[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
/* 25        9.76    11.04    11.98    12.55    12.74    12.55
   30       14.06    15.89    17.25    18.07    18.35    18.07
   35       19.14    21.63    23.47    24.60    24.98    24.60
   40       24.99    28.25    30.66    32.13    32.63    32.13
   45       31.63    35.76    38.80    40.66    41.29    40.66
*/
```

Why does the output repeat the 4th column for the 6th column and can I get help fixing it.

The code is to calculate R(θ) = Vo^2 sin(2θ)/g with different values for starting angle and initial velocity.

Comment: How are you declaring and creating `trajectory`?

Comment: And what value are you using for `gravity`, and what type is it?

Comment: On mobile so sorry if format is wrong.  double[][] trajectory = new double [speed.length][deg.length];   double gravity = 9.8;  The question got answered by Eran. I couldn't figure out what was wrong but the code works.

Comment: Yeah, when I was looking at the code I figured it was just because the math came out the same, since there weren't any obvious errors. I just didn't know why. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the 4th and 6th columns can be different only is `Math.sin(2 * Math.toRadians(deg[j]))` would produce different value for `Math.sin(2 * Math.toRadians(40))` and `Math.sin(2 * Math.toRadians(50))`.

However,

```
sin(2*θ) == sin(180-2*θ) == sin(2*(90-θ))
```

Therefore you get the same results for the column of `θ == 40` and the column of `θ == 50`.

There is nothing wrong with your calculation. As you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion), the maximum distance is obtained if θ is 45 degrees, so it's not surprising that you get the same distances (which are slightly smaller than the max distance) for 40 and 50 degrees.